# How to load the aplpack packages

Tags: r

I am trying to open the `aplpack packages` in R, it has no problem with downloading the packages, but when I open the packages `library("aplapck")` . The program "freezed", it just keep loading forever. What should i do now?

Comment: have you tried restarting?

Comment: @RAB Yes! I even tried it in R studio, same thing happens...